# Plot 15 minute interval data with days and months as the x axis ticks

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have data logged on a 15 minute interval. I want to plot this data and have the x axis display a minor tick at each day, and a major tick each month. Here's a snippet of what I'm trying to do using Jan and Feb.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

#make some data
t = np.arange(0, 5664, 1) # Jan and Feb worth of 15 minute steps
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t) # data measured

#plot the data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

#select formatting
days = mdates.DayLocator()
daysfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d')
months = mdates.MonthLocator()
monthsfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('\n%b')
```

From the documentation and other Q&A's I have read and tried to piece together in my head, I understand that I need to tell matplotlib the formats I want to use for the x-axis. Here is where I am getting confused. I can't figure out how to indicate that the plot data is every 15 minutes (1440 samples per minor tick), and so when I show the plot there is nothing displayed on the graph. Or at least I think that's the cause...

```
#apply formatting
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthsfmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(days)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(daysfmt)

#select dates
datemin = dt.datetime.strptime('01/01/17', '%d/%m/%y')
datemax = dt.datetime.strptime('28/02/17', '%d/%m/%y')
ax.set_xlim(datemin, datemax)

plt.show()
```

Plot Results

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There, working ;)

There were two problems with your code:

1. you were plotting t and s, but setting the x axis with a wrong scale
2. you were only plotting the numerical noise of sin(x) because you were always using multiples of 2pi as argument to sin, and sin(n*2pi) = 0, for any integer n

Complete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import num

py as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates



#make some data
t = np.arange(0, 5664, 0.1) # Jan and Feb worth of 15 minute steps
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t) # data measured

#plot the data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#ax.plot(t, s)

#select formatting
days = mdates.DayLocator()
daysfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d')
months = mdates.MonthLocator()
monthsfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('\n%b')

#apply formatting
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthsfmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(days)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(daysfmt)

#select dates
datemin = dt.datetime.strptime('01/01/17', '%d/%m/%y')
datemax = dt.datetime.strptime('28/02/17', '%d/%m/%y')


t0 = dt.datetime(2017,1,1)
t_datetime = [ t0 + dt.timedelta(minutes=15*t_) for t_ in t ]

ax.plot(t_datetime,s)

ax.set_xlim(t0, t_datetime[-1])


plt.show()
```